# Python - Find Xpath value then click button

Tags: python, pycharm

I'd like to get some advise on how to find a value in certain xpath value, time in my case: 7:30pm.
Then in the same level click on an add button. (there are many other same button in the page with a different time value). Reference to attached picture, really appreciate any help.

[image: My Code]

Comment: Can;t you just right-click the elements and copy full xpath?

Comment: Before you get your question closed: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 . 
 NEVER have images of code or exceptions.  See http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode and http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: probably every web browser in DevTools has function to get XPATH on right click. But you could try also find unque ID or CLASS for element. If there is many similar elements then you can get all of them and later use `index` -  `all_times[1]`  - to work only with one element.

Comment: Daisho: The xpath contains many results, I can use xpath find the button itself, but the table will get added with with new additional available time for booking everyday. So the button address is dynamic and I can't really use it to identify the link lement.

Comment: Lakshya Raj: Thanks for the comment, I tried to modify my post but I wasn't able to just add code, it was mentioning that I can't upload photos but I wasn't able to remove it

Comment: furas: Thank you so much, I'm an beginner(only had some super simple Macro VBA experience before). Your comment helped a lot. Will spend time try to understand your code and test the technique out :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably every web browser in `DevTools` has function to get `XPATH` on right click.

But you could try also find unique `ID` or `CLASS` (or other unique value - ie. `style=...`) for element. Or unique value for its parent or grandparent.

If there are many similar elements then you can get all of them and later use `index` -  `all_times[1]`  - to work only with one element.

It seems your element has unique `headers="Times"` which you could use in `xpath`.

You can also relative `xpath` (starting with dot `.`) and search partially - first find `tr`, next find `.//td[@headers="Times"]` in this `tr` and next find `.//td[@headers="Avaliable"]/div/a` in the same `tr`

---

**EDIT:**

If I couldn't find unique elements then I would get all `tr` because it is parent for `Times` and `Avaliable` and I can use relative xpath to search one  `Times` and one `Avaliable` in single `tr` - and then use `for`-loop

```
 all_tr = html.xpath("//tr")

 for tr in all_tr: 

     # relative xpath in `tr` (using `.` at start)
     header = tr.xpath('.//td[@headers="Times"')

     if "7:30" in header[0].text: 

         # relative xpath in `tr` (using `.` at start)
         avaliable = tr.xpath('.//td[@headers="Avaliable"]')

         avaliable[0].click()
```

Comment: The problem is that there are many headers="Times", and they are all the same. (they keep adding to it as well every day).

Comment: manually calclulate which one you need  and use `[index]` to get this one which you expect.  And if you need exactly with time `7:30pm.` then get all `tr` and check time in every `tr` until you find `7:30pm`. You don't have to use only xpath for this. Eventually you can try to use `xpath` with `contains(@text, '7:30pm')`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm new to programing, and I'm having hard time to post the original code in my posting :) Apologize for using a picture of the code.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, I'll need to store two variables, both all times and button click link into an index, say: all_times[1], and compare 7:30pm with the information in the index, then I should be able to call the click link address?

Comment: I would get all `tr` because it is parent for `Header` and `Avaliable` - and then use `for tr in all_tr: header = xpath(...) ; if "7:30" in header.text: xpath(...Avaliable...).click()`. I add pseudo code in answer

Comment: How can I get all tr and store all those information into all_times[]? I just noticed the code you posted. Thank you so much!!! I'll try your technique right now :)

Comment: xpath gives list - but I would get all tr and later use **relative** xpath to search single `Times` inside every `tr` and single `Avaliable` in the same `tr`.

Comment: all_tr = html.xpath("//tr")
NameError: name 'html' is not defined                                         I still can't figure out how should I define html,I've tried few links of the page but I wasn't able to get it working

Comment: it is only pseudocode - I assume you use `selenium` and it would be `html = driver` and it would use `find_element_by_xpath`. But if you use `BeautifulSoup` then it make no sense bacause it can't click - it would need to use `requests` to send data directly to server.

Comment: You are right, I'm trying with selenium.                                 all_tr = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr")                                      for tr in all_tr:                                                                                            
    header = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[@headers='Times']")            print(header)

Comment: gives me a lot of lines like these: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="3ffddb871a4eaed65ede621f892b8bf1", element="3ac2eec9-7de3-48ad-a7a9-c84abd213485")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="3ffddb871a4eaed65ede621f892b8bf1", element="08c8f2ea-4da0-4e62-b863-9681a84ce5d7")>,

Comment: and now you have to use `for`-loop to work with every `element` separatelly. And you can use `element.find_element_by_xpath`  to find something inside element, or `element.text` to get text, or `element.get_attribut(...)` to get some attribute. Simply you have to read documentation for [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)